# why i am getting mixed content issue while redirecting

Tags: html, oracle, http-redirect, mixed-content

I am getting error while redirecting from http://example.com domain to https://example1.com domain.

I got this problem when we are doing cross browsing (from IE to chrome/Edge).
in IE works fine but issue in Chrome/Edge.

any alternative please suggest !!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Also, you haven't provided any information to work with. We don't even see how you redirect the user and/or what the full source code is.

Comment: What does this have to do with the database.

Comment: Please include any error messages you are receiving.